# Hide/ Show jQuery UI Tooltip's Arrow

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to change tooltip position based on `click` event. I know how to move the tooltip to the left or right of the hovered element.

What become my problem here is positioning the arrow to the right when the tooltip is on the left and vice versa.

To achieve it, I am trying to hide one of the arrow when it is not fit the tooltip's position with `hide()` function, but it doesn't seem to work.

`$('.right .ui-tooltip-content::after').hide()`

- What's the correct jquery selector for pseudo element, in this case the tooltip's arrow?
- Is there other better ways to achieve what I want above? If so, please share it with us!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK..! I solved the problem.

Since pseudo element is not the part of DOM element, then select it with jquery won't work. So, I just append css style to the head in order to manipulate the visibility of the arrow:

`$('head').append("<style> .right .ui-tooltip-content:after { display : none;} </style>");`